# Help with evaluation of the differential of a BSplineFunction?

Tags: functions, random, splines, differentials

It can be useful to generate a *smooth* random function over $[-L,L]$ with `BSplineFunction`:

```
L=10;
SeedRandom[1]
f[x_] = BSplineFunction[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 20], SplineClosed -> True][x/(2*L)]
```

It is easy to plot `f[x]`

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> {{-L, L}, All}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.5]
```

[image]

However, sometimes we also want to use its derivatives in a numerical computation, for example, `D[f[x], {x, 3}]`. Before using it, let us observe its curve first, which becomes many steps! Obviously, such a function is NOT the derivative of `f[x]` and cannot be used in numerical computations.

```
Plot[Evaluate[D[f[x], {x, 3}]], {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> {{-L, L}, All}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.5]
```

[image]

I have not figured out the reason. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's no surprise that you get a step function with 3 derivatives, since the default [`SplineDegree`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplineDegree) is 3. If you want to take 3 derivatives, you should up the [`SplineDegree`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplineDegree):

```
L = 10;
SeedRandom[1]
f[x_] = BSplineFunction[RandomReal[{-1,1}, 20], SplineClosed->True, SplineDegree->5][x/(2*L)];
```

Then:

```
Plot[f'''[x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]